# Checking for Remote Sessions

Tags: .net, powershell, network-programming, remote-access, windows-server-2012

I want to create an application that checks for and notifies if a remote session exists on a server. I do not know if remote access products like *Bomgar*, *gotomeeting*, *gotoassist*, and others use Terminal Services or not.

It looks like `GetSystemMetrics'` `SM_REMOTECONTROL` and `SM_REMOTESESSION` refer only remote sessions connecting through Windows Terminal Services.

I have just looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190194/get-list-of-all-remote-sessions), but this refers to PowerShell sessions.

So, my general question is what family of .NET APIs deal with creating, configuring, and detecting remote access?

***Edit Since Posting:***

I have just looked at this other [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fe16191a-5d49-4271-bdb2-1566c107bd24/detect-if-a-session-is-a-remote-desktop-or-b-remoteapp?forum=winserverTS) in Microsoft TechNet, and it appears I need to get a list of processes, and find out if `rdpinit.exe` and `rdpshell.exe` are in each process' process list, but will that cover some of the well-known remote access products, and is there an API to do this?

Comment: "will that cover all remote access products" - I don't see how you would be able to test for the existence of something you don't know exists.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Good point. I edited the post.

Comment: Can't you utilize `netstat -ano` and parse for foreign addresses then reverse the PID for the process name?

Answer (score 1):

How about the `NetSessionEnum` function from `netapi32.dll`?  Boe Prox has a great article on it:  https://learn-powershell.net/2016/08/07/viewing-net-sessions-using-powershell-and-pinvoke/

There are already pre-written PowerShell scripts that p/invoke it but if you want to roll your own, here's p/invoke.net for the signature:  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.NetSessionEnum

As a side note, MS released a blog article with a script that detailed ACL modification to the registry a few months back to actually block this since it allows for non-administrator, remote session enumeration of Windows machines.

Comment: In which .net Assembly is NetSessionEnum?

Comment: none... that's why you must use platform invocation services (p/invoke) to access the underlying Windows API.  the NetSessionEnum function resides in System32\netapi32.dll

Comment: The blog article by Boe Prox (he's awesome btw) that I linked has a script he wrote that you can reference or use.  And there are others on the net as well.